# Command error "amplify configure" : installation error aws amplify

Tags: amazon-web-services, installation, aws-amplify

I tried to install aws amplify.  But when I typed those commands in cmd window
then an error message came out.

```
>amplify configure

"amplify" is not an internal or external command .....
```

In this case, what should I do?
--I'm using Windows10

Answer (score 1):

You need to install the amplify-cli first.

```
npm install -g @aws-amplify/cli
```

If you have already done so, opening a new commandline and typing

```
amplify configure
```

Should begin the configuration process.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install Amplify CLI and configure it first.

1. Install `Node.js` in your system
2. Install `amplify cli` using the command

```
npm install -g @aws-amplify/cli
```